# Algebraic approach to analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

Can topics and foundations of real analysis be interpreted and profitably explained in terms of abstract algebraic structures?

If so, what papers or books (accessible to undergraduate students) focus on real analysis in that way?

Comment: i got take the course real analysis and abstract algebra course during undergraduate.

Comment: P.S. I apologize for the naivety of my question , but I would really appreciate some thoughtful answers.

Comment: your question sounds good, i no think this before.

Comment: I think the question doesn't make much sense. $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique complete ordered field, and fields are algebraic structures, but completeness makes the jump from algebra to analysis, and analysis stays analysis even if you work with algebraic structures. Of course, there are big overlaps between algebra and analysis (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+analysis), but you seem to ask for an algebraic foundation of real analysis?

Comment: The construction of the real numbers out of the rational ones can be made with the help of ring theory, ideals, quotient rings and all that. Imo the nicest proof. You can also prove quite easily that differentiation/indefinite integration are in fact linear transformations in suitable linear spaces. You need, of course, to know some linear and abstract algebra for this

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, I would like to know more about how to formulate the basis of analysis in algebraic terms.

Comment: @Timbuc Are there books that use this kind of approach?

Comment: @Dal,  you can try this: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kahn/reals07.pdf For someone with some calculus knowledge there are lots and lots of details that can be skipped, so don't get afraid by the papes's length. The book "The Real Numbers and Real Analysis", by Ethan Bloch has a rather thorough and nice, albeit slightly lengthy, construction of the integers, the rationals and the reals (Dedekind Cuts). Chapter IX of Lang's "Undergraduate Algebra" also does ring theory to construct the real numbers.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You might be interested in Peter Freyd's work on "algebraic real analysis".  He axiomitizes the interval $[0,1]$ as the terminal object in a category of coalgebras with a "concatenate" operation, and developes a bit of real analysis from the premise (including a universal property for integration).

Comment: @Steven I'm aware of this, but this is still analysis in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at *Foundations of Modern Analysis* by Dieudonné. It does differential calculus in the context of Banach spaces, and takes a similarly abstract approach to integration, including Haar measure on locally compact groups.

However, it's too abstract to be a good source if you're learning analysis for the first time (for well over 99% of people, anyway).